# roboframework script issue

Tags: python, robotframework

In RobotFramework, I am trying to execute a command on server, taking the output in a variable and comparing the output as Empty or not empty but I am getting an error.

Robot Script:

```
${redRelease}   Execute Command As Root And Return Result   ${SERVER}   cat /etc/redhat-release | grep '6.7'

Run Keyword If  '${redRelease}'=='${Empty}' Should Contain  xxx    yyyy
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Evaluating expression ''
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)'==''' failed:
SyntaxError: no viable alternative at character ''' (<string>, line 1)
```

How can I compare the output of the grep command to be Empty or non Empty?

Comment: What does Execute Command As Root And Return Result do? My guess is that is somehow modifies reply from server.

Comment: Yes, it executes a command as root user and returns the result.

Comment: Your code works for me when I use  Execute Command from SSHLibrary. I don't understand how '${Empty}' becomes '''. Log ${Empty} just before you run "Run Keyword If...." to see you have not accidentally set ${Empty} to another value.

Answer (score 0):

RoboFramework provides an in-built library "SSHLibrary" which helps in dealing the same.

For example :

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SSHLibrary


*** Variables ***
${HOST}           127.0.0.1
${USERNAME}       labadmin
${PASSWORD}       root123
${command}        cat /etc/*release

*** Test Cases ***

Login_to_server
    Open Connection    ${HOST}
    Login    ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
    ${output}    Execute Command    ${command}
    Should Contain    ${output}    "Ubuntu"
```

Modify the above snippet according to your setup.